# How to measure edges?

Tags: modeling

Using blender 2.82a. Current documentation states to enable "Edge Length" in the overlay options. Doing so and selecting an edge always shows 2m or 6.56' (depending on units selected) regardless of size and its clearly not correct. What is the correct way to measure an edge? Maybe this feature is broken? Image example attached.

[image]

Comment: Did you scale the object? Will apply object scale fix the problem?

Comment: Where would I find apply object scale?

Comment: `Ctrl + A` in object mode